# Custom On/Off Image iOS 7.0 UI Switch

Tags: ios, xcode, uiswitch

In iOS 7 switches don't allow custom on/off images by default.  While I can still set them in the Interface Builder it doesn't show up.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/TransitionGuide.pdf

The transition guide merely notes that it isn't on by default anymore.  Presumably there is a way to change that so I do use the images I have.

Comment: I have same problem. Very strange that Apple decided to remove this functionality.

Comment: strange is that it is removed but form in IB contains fields to fill:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Can you use a UIButton instead, using the "selected" state to mean "on"?

Comment: This is what ended up happening to an extent.  It meant rebaking some art, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Have the same problem. Before coming to this answer I used this approach, but it not as elegant as it would be with a switch element.

Answer (score 13):

Apple never let this feature go live... I believe you can file a bug report about it if you want to see it in the future...

I've got around this issue by using a drop in replacement called [SevenSwitch](https://github.com/bvogelzang/SevenSwitch).

Comment: After a lot of research, this is the best possible solution I have found so far and is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

Download [these](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.SevenSwitch/tree/master/Classes) two files:

```
SevenSwitch.h 
SevenSwitch.m
```

Include them to your project, it is very easy for customizing.