# UISwitch on / off image not working iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, uiswitch

I'm new to iOS, while i'm trying to add on/off images to UISwitch in the UIStoryboard, it's not working. It is deprecated in iOS 10. I tried through code also but it's not working.

```
elseSwitch.onImage = UIImage(named: "switchOff")
elseSwitch.offImage = UIImage(named: "switchOff")
```

Comment: i have a code but in objective c not in swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why UISwitch onImage/offImage properties are not working on iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843747/why-uiswitch-onimage-offimage-properties-are-not-working-on-ios-7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom On/Off Image iOS 7.0 UI Switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410300/custom-on-off-image-ios-7-0-ui-switch)

Comment: You have set both states to `switchOff ` ... do you have a `switchOn` Image?

Comment: In iOS 6 and earlier, the image displayed when the switch is in the on/off position.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`onImage` and `offImage` has no effect on `UISwitch` anymore as you've discovered :)

Instead you can use

- `onTintColor` to set the tint color of the switch when it is turned on.
- `tintColor` to set the tint color of the switch when it is turned off.
- `thumbTintColor` to set the tint color of the thumb.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiswitch)

Here is an example using those three properties:

```
@IBOutlet weak var toggleSwitch: UISwitch! {
    didSet {
        toggleSwitch.isOn = true
        toggleSwitch.tintColor = UIColor.red
        toggleSwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.blue
        toggleSwitch.thumbTintColor = UIColor.brown
    }
}
```

Which gives me this beautiful switch when turned off

[image: off switch]

And this when turned on

[image: on switch]

(I'm a developer not a designer if you can't tell ;))

So in your case you could use some shade of grey for the `onTintColor` and `tintColor` to get you to this result

[image]

[image]

Hope that helps you.